# objective-c share image to Instagram from my iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, instagram, social-media

I've spent a long time searching how to share photo from iOS application to Instagram. Other social media like Twitter are working fine. I have found a lot of resources on Google but it's not working.
Please I need some help to add Instagram share button to the UIActivityViewController that already has Twitter share button. 
Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)shareBtnClicked {
    NSString *textToShare = @"Share \r";
    NSURL *url = newsC.URL;
    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, url];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    //this array should add the activities that I don’t want
    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[ UIActivityTypePrint,
                                    UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToVimeo
                                    ];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use below method:

```
 -(void)instaPostImage
    {
        NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your image url"];
        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
        UIImage *imgShare = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];

        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) //check for App is install or not
        {
            UIImage *imageToUse = imgShare;
            NSString *documentDirectory=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
            NSString *saveImagePath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];
            NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUse);
            [imageData writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];
            NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveImagePath];
            self.documentController=[[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc]init];
            self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageURL];
            self.documentController.delegate = self;
            self.documentController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing"], @"InstagramCaption", nil];
            self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
            UIViewController *vc = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
            [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(1, 1, 1, 1) inView:vc.view animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        DisplayAlertWithTitle(@"Instagram not found", @"")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked fine with twitter but no Facebook share button although i'm logged in to my Facebook account.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
- (IBAction)shareBtnClicked {
    NSString *textToShare = @"Share \r";
    NSURL *url = newsC.URL;

    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *imgShare = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

   NSArray *objectsToShare = @[imgShare, textToShare];
   UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

   //this array should add the activities that I don’t want
   NSArray *excludeActivities = @[ UIActivityTypePrint,
                                UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                UIActivityTypePostToVimeo
                                ];

   activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
   [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: I tried several versions with the document interaction controller and none worked, thanks for this version it was flawless.